# Get a model's associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to get a model's associations programatically?

I can pull columns but the type integer isnt verbose enough. I'd like a hash of each association defined for a model and what type it is.

If you're curious I am building generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [reflections](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflections) method as a class method and instance method
and [reflect_on_all_associations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_all_associations) as a class method.

Answer (score 0):

nvm i found it in another post

`reflect_on_all_associations`

is what I was looking for.

Comment: In that case please vote to close your question as a duplicate.